# Should I duplicate data in my DB?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL DB containing entry for pages of a website.
Let's say it has fields like:

```
Table pages:

id  |  title  | content | date | author
```

Each of the pages can be voted by users, so I have two other tables

```
Table users:
id  |  name  | etc etc etc

Table votes:
id  |  id_user | id_page | vote
```

Now, I have a page where I show a list of the pages (10-50 at a time) with various information along with the average vote of the page.

So, I was wondering if it were better to:

a) Run the query to display the pages (note that this is already fairly heavy as it queries three tables) and then for each entry do another query to calculate the mean vote (or add a 4th join to the main query?).

or

b) Add an "average vote" column to the pages table, which I will update (along with the vote table) when an user votes the page.

nico

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the database for what it's meant for; option a is by far your best bet.  It's worth noting that your query isn't actually particularly heavy, joining three tables; SQL really excels at this sort of thing.

Be cautious of this sort of attempt at premature optimization of SQL; SQL is far more efficient at what it does than most people think it is.

Note that another benefit from using your option a is that there's less code to maintain, and less chance of data diverging as code gets updated; it's a lifecycle benefit, and they're too often ignored for miniscule optimization benefits.

Answer (score 1):

You might "repeat yourself" (violate DRY) for the sake of performance.  The trade-offs are (a) extra storage, and (b) extra work in keeping everything self-consistent within your DB.

There are advantages/disadvantages both ways.  Optimizing too early has its own set of pitfalls, though.

Comment: The problem is that this "optimization" could cause some serious problems with contention on the pages table with a very popular page; to wit, you might gain a very small amount of performance, but that's setting things up for an epic fail, when one page becomes very popular, and the contention for that page's record goes above 100%.  In this case, that potential (hard) fail case must be considered in the tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, for this issue, I would recommend redundent information. Multiple votes for multiple pages can really create a heavy load for a server, in my opinion. If you forsee to have real traffic on your website, of course... :-)

Comment: I think you're missing the possible problem of multiple votes for the same page; the calculation of the aggregate information every single time and the record lock on that page's record could be crushing to the server for a single popular page.

Comment: That's not a problem if you store the number of votes and the sum of all votes instead of the average. Calculation wouldn't be a real issue, then.

Comment: calculation isn't really the main issue; it's the record lock on the pages table.  No duplication of information also means no contention over that resource.

Comment: Again, if you store the number of votes and the sum of all votes in the pages table, you will be able to calculate the average without locking anything else than the row in the pages table. Update of this one row will happen each time another line is inserted in votes, but believing my experience, that's an acceptable overhead.